# Reduce this polynomial in $\mathbb Z_2[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

In $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ reduce $x^5+x+1$

I have attempted to find roots by inputting the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$

For example $f(0) = (0^2+0+1) = 1$ (not a root)
$f(1) = (1^2+1+1) = 3$ (not a root)

So i'm led to believe this is irreducible.

Comment: Have you tried factoring this into a degree-3 and a degree-2 polynomial?

Answer (score 1):

You have shown that it has no linear factor. There's still the possibility that it factorises as quadratic-times-cubic.

There's only one irreducible quadratic mod $2$, namely $x^2+x+1$. So if your expression factorises, then one of the factors is $x^2+x+1$. Can you find the other factor (if it exists), or prove that there is no corresponding cubic factor?